# SetTimeout JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, sweetalert

Estoy tratando de establecer un tipo de dalay cuando obtengo respuesta de la solicitud Ajax, entonces por alguna razón el sweetAlert se cierra automáticamente, entonces, lo que pretendo es establecer un timeout aquí el código:

```
jQuery.ajax({

            url:'accion.php',

            method:"POST",

            data:{estudiante_id:estudiante_id, action:action},

            dataType:"json",
            timeout : 30000

            success:function(json){

            if(json.Estatus == "Activa"){
               
                   swal("Membresia Actualizada!", "Aún cuentas con tu membresia de Guias de México!", "success"); 
   //colocar delay o timeout                
        
                
            }else{
                swal("Oh no!", "Tu membresia expiró, comunicate con tu guiadora lo más pronto posible", "error");
                location.href ="../../../../logout";
            }

            }

        })
```

Incluso antes del `location.href`, el chiste es mantener el sweetAlert abierto o hasta que se presione el `botón de ok`, ignorando el demás código principal

Comment: Estás pensando en hacer que swal se comporte como un diálogo de confirmación de los años 90, que efectivamente se apropie del foco y detenga el eventLoop hasta que el visitante interactúe?

Comment: Ajam, mantener el swal por cierto tiempo

Comment: No hay problema con cerrarlo programáticamente después de unos segundos, pero estás asumiendo, equivocadamente, que al abrir swal éste adquiere el foco y necesariamente demanda una interacción. No es así. Es un simple contenedor que se hace visible. Creo que el enunciado mete innnecesariamente ajax a la ecuación, pero ajax es anecdótico. La pregunta debiera ser cómo pausar la ejecución a la espera de que el visitante interactúe con swal

Comment: Alguna sugerencia en código?

Comment: No. Sólo quiero ayudar a enmarcar bien la pregunta porque -así como está- la rama "membresía actualizada" no sugiere cuál es el comportamiento actual que quieres evitar. A simple vista el swal queda a la vista indefinidamente y eso es todo

Answer (score 3):

El comportamiento normal de SweetAlert es mostrar la ventana y continuar ejecutando el código, sin embargo, no es necesario crear un temporizador, sino [usar promesas](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises) para realizar otras acciones cuando se cierre la ventana y basta con encadenar el método `.then()` que incluya una función con las instrucciones deseadas.

```js
// Lo separé en varias líneas para mejor lectura, pero no es necesario
swal(
    "Oh no!",
    "Tu membresia expiró, comunicate con tu guiadora lo más pronto posible",
    "error"
).then(() => {
    // Puedes borrar esta línea, es solo para probar
    console.log('Aquí rediriges a la otra página');
    // Descomenta la siguiente línea para redirigir
    // location.href ="../../../../logout";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sí, pero has de cuenta que aparece el swal, pero en cuestión de 2 segundos se cierra, no deja ni apretar al botón de OK, entonces si pongo el then, seria lo mismo, no?

Comment: @karlDomínguez, no es lo mismo. ¿Probaste el fragmento de código? ¿Trataste de hacer la redirección dentro del `.then()`?

Answer (score 1):

No se mucho de ajax, pero aportando a lo que menciona @Triby podrías hacer la redirección dentro del `.then()` y usando un `setTimeout()` puedes controlar el delay.

```js
timeout = 5000;
swal(
    "Oh no!",
    "Tu membresia expiró, comunicate con tu guiadora lo más pronto posible",
    "error"
).then(() => {
    console.log('Aquí rediriges a la otra página');
    setTimeout(() => {
        location.href = "https://www.google.com";
    }, timeout);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```